# Auto complete textbox from mdf (master SQL Server database file)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, autocomplete, textbox, mdf

I'm trying to use an autocomplete textbox, fed from a SQL Serve `.mdf` database file.

This is my code:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select col_name  FROM college ", cn)

If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then cn.Open()

Dim ds As New DataSet

Dim sqda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
sqda.Fill(ds, "college")

Dim col As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
    col.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("col_name").ToString())
Next

TextBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col
TextBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
```

Since I am using SQL Server, the data not showing in the list.

I think its needs to use character **N**  like

Insert data into SQL Server as:

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("insert into college (col_name) values (N'" & TextBox1.Text.Trim & "')", cn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your database objects local so you can control the closing and disposing. Using...End Using blocks handle this even if there is an error.

Always use parameters to avoid Sql injection.

In .net Char supports Unicode so strings (which are arrays of Char) also support Unicode. As long as the field in Sql Server is of type NVarChar. I don't see a problem

```vb
Private Sub SetUpAutoComplete()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Select col_name  FROM college ", cn)
            cn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Dim col As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        col.Add(row("col_name").ToString)
    Next
    'Just to check if we have some data
    Debug.Print(col.Count.ToString)
    TextBox3.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    TextBox3.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col
    TextBox3.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    SetUpAutoComplete()
End Sub

Private Sub InsertCollege()
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your Connection string")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("insert into college (col_name) values (@Name)", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text.Trim
            cn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: not work ... my problem that I'm write the data in Arabic language , so that the word not showing  because i use database.mdf   if i use database.sql there is no error and work fine so the problem in the Unicode  of .mdf

Comment: my problem not in insert data >>> its in the auto complete in textbox

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by " i use database.mdf " You don't access the server files directly. When you say "i use database.sql there is no error and work fine" You are mean you get the text from the file and use it as the command text? What is in the .sql file. The .sql file is a query running on Sql Server which accesses the .mdf. Sorry, this might be a language problem but .net works with unicode and should not have a problem with Arabic.

Comment: "my problem not in insert data" You will have a problem if you don't use parameters. Sql injection is the easiest way to corrupt a database.

Comment: i mean by .mdf  its a database as show in picture [link](https://i.ibb.co/mhPb70B/21-07-2019-09-47-45.png)  so i need some think like use the char **"N" **

Comment: i found the problem that if enable **Multiline** for textbox then the data will not appear  [link](https://i.ibb.co/wKjBM5R/21-07-2019-10-31-51.png) so that it should be stay in default ,,, why this happen